# Git pull fails (403) without prompting for password

Tags: git, netbeans, phpstorm

After switching an existing project from NetBeans to PhpStorm (version 2019.1.2), I tried to do a simple `git pull` from PhpStorm.

Instead of prompting for the credentials of the remote repository, PhpStorm displayed an error message:

> Git Pull Failed: unable to access 'https://username@example.com/repository': The requested URL returned error: 403

---

Interestingly, `git pull` also fails from the terminal, with a similar error message:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://username@example.com/repository': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: And if you do `git pull` from the terminal?

Comment: @msanford It turns out it also fails from the terminal (403 error as well). Adding the username to the URL is something NetBeans does, and it's clearly a bad idea.

Comment: Are you _able_ to use ssh as a protocol? If so I'll write something up. (If not I'm out of ideas, I use almost exclusively ssh myself...)

Comment: If you are able to use ssh, you can test your authentication with `ssh -vv git@example.com` and see if you have a successful authentication. (Note the username is very often `git`, _not_ your username) I [suggest using public keys](https://help.github.com/en/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) for that purpose as they are secure and extremely convenient.

Comment: @msanford No, I can't use SSH with this specific repository. But I don't need to: it works properly once the username is removed from the remote URL.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the remote URL:

- It uses HTTPS (not SSH)
- It **includes the username** (`username@`), which was added by NetBeans
- It doesn't include the password

The solution is to **remove the username from the remote URL**:

- **Before:** https://username@example.com/repository
- **After:** https://example.com/repository

Either from PhpStorm (**Git** > **Remotes...** > *Select your remote* > **Edit**),

Which will cause PhpStorm to prompt for the username and password,

Or, from the terminal:

```
git remote set-url origin https://example.com/repository
```

---

Alternatively, you could probably add the password in the URL (not tested), such as https://username:password@example.com/repository, however, for obvious security reasons, you don't want to do that.

Comment: Yes, definitely don't do that last thing; there are many ways of providing authentication securely to git.